# Django choice field(dropdown) restrict according to user type for multiuser type

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have multi user types in my django app where the user can change the status of something usertype a has options to perform create a task,close(choice fields) while usertype b has option to accept the task created by usertype a and mark finish. how do i restrict them in the form according to the user type when the usertype a clicks on form he should see only close under dropdown whereas the usertype b has to see only accept and finish option in dropdown.

**models.py**

```
class todo(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    info = models.TextField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'created_by',blank=True,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0,opened),
        ('1','Accepted'),
        ('2','Completed'),
        ('3','finish')
    )

    status = models.CharField('Status',choices=STATUS_CHOICES,max_length = 100,default = 'Open')
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('title', 'info')



class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ('title', 'info','status')
```